# Atualizar campos dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso que o meu código atualize o campo Acréscimo quando é alterado o valor do campo Total para um valor maior que o valor do Sub.Total ou atualize o campo Desconto quando o campo Total for menor que o campo Sub.Total com o valor da diferença, e quando é acrescentado um valor no campo Acréscimo ou no campo Desconto ele atualize o campo Total.

No meu código o campo Total já está funcionando corretamente quando é atualizado o campo Acréscimo ou Desconto, porém preciso que trabalhe ao inverso também, como coloquei acima, ou seja, atualize também os campo Acréscimo e Desconto quando alterado o campo Total.

[image: Campos]

Este é o código HTML

```
        <div id="DivOcultaBaixa" class="" style="display: none;">
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Sub. Total:</div>
                <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="subtotal" id="subtotal"  readonly="readonly" type="text" value="<?php echo number_format($soma_saldo, 2, ',', '.') ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Acréscimo:</div>
                <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="acrescimo" id="acrescimo"  type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Desconto:</div>
                <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="desconto" id="desconto"  type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput"><strong>TOTAL:</strong></div>
                <input type="text" id="total_val" style="background: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;" name="total_val" class="input-medium focused span6 result" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo number_format($soma_saldo, 2, ',', '.') ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                    <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Valor Pago:</div>
                    <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="pagoparc" id="pagoparc"  type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group span3">
                    <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput"><strong>SALDO:</strong></div>
                    <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" style="background: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;" name="saldodev" id="saldodev"  type="text" value="<?php echo number_format($soma_saldo, 2, ',', '.') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Script js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Quando o valor do campo mudar...
    $('.calc').change(function(){
        var subtotal = parseFloat($('#subtotal').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;
        var acrescimo = parseFloat($('#acrescimo').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;
        var desconto = parseFloat($('#desconto').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;
        var pagoparc = parseFloat($('#pagoparc').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;

        //O total 
        var total = subtotal + acrescimo - desconto;
        var saldo = total - pagoparc;

        $('#total_val').val(number_format(total,2, ',', '.'));
        $('#saldodev').val(number_format(saldo,2, ',', '.'));

    });
});

function number_format( number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep ) {
var n = number, c = isNaN(decimals = Math.abs(decimals)) ? 2 : decimals;
var d = dec_point == undefined ? "," : dec_point;
var t = thousands_sep == undefined ? "." : thousands_sep, s = n < 0 ? "-" : "";
var i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");}
```

Comment: [O que você já tentou?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Tentei usar a mesma lógica e também if (se o valor total for diferente do valor sub. total), não tive êxito.

Comment: Pode colocar aqui o código que falta? Por exemplo o que faz `number_format()`?

Comment: Adicionei o código number_format() @Sergio

Comment: @IrioBroleisFilho é isto que pretende? http://jsfiddle.net/pfok6a4s/

Comment: Por uma questão de segurança, eu sugiro que você faça os cálculos pelo PHP e retorne os resultados via AJAX pelo método `$.post()`. Ficar fazendo tantas tratativas pelo javascript não é muito inteligente, qualquer um pode alterar seus valores.

Answer (score 3):

Cara esta bem confuso qual é a sua dificuldade, então vou dar um exemplo de **como atualizar um campo com os valores de outro.**

Viu como eu simplifiquei?, sugiro que edite sua pergunta para que fique bem definido o problema, e não coloque na pergunta todos os demais problemas iguais, apenas um exemplo da dificuldade já é suficiente, assim que receber uma resposta teste em um único caso, se der certo basta aplica-lo aos demais assim sua pergunta fica curta e fácil de entender.

a Partir desse exemplo abaixo me diga o que gostaria que fosse diferente?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivOcultaBaixa" class="" >
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Sub. Total:</div>
                <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="subtotal" id="subtotal"  readonly="readonly" type="text" value="40"/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Acréscimo:</div>
                <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="acrescimo" id="acrescimo"  type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Desconto:</div>
                <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="desconto" id="desconto"  type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput"><strong>TOTAL:</strong></div>
                <input type="text" id="total_val" style="background: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;" name="total_val" class="input-medium focused span6 result" readonly="readonly" value="40"/>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                    <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput">Valor Pago:</div>
                    <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" name="pagoparc" id="pagoparc"  type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group span3">
                    <div class="control span4" for="focusedInput"><strong>SALDO:</strong></div>
                    <input class="input-medium focused span6 calc" style="background: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;" name="saldodev" id="saldodev"  type="text" value="40"/>
                </div>
        </div>
    <script src="js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Quando o valor do campo mudar...
            $('.calc').keyup(function(){
                var subtotal = parseFloat($('#subtotal').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;
                var acrescimo = parseFloat($('#acrescimo').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;
                var desconto = parseFloat($('#desconto').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;
                var pagoparc = parseFloat($('#pagoparc').val().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) || 0.00;

                //O total 
                var total = subtotal + acrescimo - desconto;
                var saldo = total - pagoparc;

                $('#total_val').val(number_format(total,2, ',', '.'));
                $('#saldodev').val(number_format(saldo,2, ',', '.'));

            });
        });

    function number_format( number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep ) {
    var n = number, c = isNaN(decimals = Math.abs(decimals)) ? 2 : decimals;
    var d = dec_point == undefined ? "," : dec_point;
    var t = thousands_sep == undefined ? "." : thousands_sep, s = n < 0 ? "-" : "";
    var i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");}
        
    </script>
</html>
```